# What relationship(s) [if any] exist between primorial primes and palindromic primes?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, open-problem, palindrome

Information on primorial primes are in the following hyperlinks:

[MathWorld - Primorial Prime](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimorialPrime.html)

[Wikipedia - Primorial Prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial_prime)

On the other hand, we have the following hyperlinks providing information on palindromic primes:

[MathWorld - Palindromic Prime](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PalindromicPrime.html)

[Wikipedia - Palindromic Prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindromic_prime)

My question at this point would be: What relationship(s) [if any] exist between primorial primes and palindromic primes?

The first few primorial primes are

$$3, 5, 7, 29, 31, 211, 2309, 2311, 30029, 200560490131, 304250263527209$$

The first few palindromic primes in base-10 are:

$$2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 101, 131, 151, 181, 191, 313, 353, 373, 383, 727, 757, 787, 797, 919, 929, 10301, 10501, 10601, 11311, 11411, 12421, 12721, 12821, 13331, 13831, 13931, 14341, 14741, 15451, 15551, 16061, 16361, 16561, 16661, 17471, 17971, 18181$$ … [sequence A002385 in OEIS](http://oeis.org/A002385)

From these two lists, the following "conjecture" appears plausible:

$\mathbf{CONJECTURE}$:  In base-10, the only prime numbers that are both primorial primes and palindromic primes are $3, 5$ and $7$.

Is this conjecture known in the literature?  If so, does it have a name (i.e., has it been proposed before)?

Comment: It is fair to question, what is your *heuristic* justification behind this conjecture?

Comment: The seems to be heuristic justification for it, because the chance a random number about $n$ is a palindrome is about $1 / \sqrt{n}$. Now because the $n$-th primorial number is about $e^n$ it would mean that the chance of it being a palindrome is about $1 / \sqrt{e}^n$.  Therefore it is likely that the only cases are small, even without taking into account the primality of the numbers.

Comment: @Houston, if you would please write out your last comment as an actual answer, I will upvote and accept.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big heuristic justification for why it is probably true.  First though, instead of thinking about a primorial prime also being a palindrome, we can simply think of it as a primorial number also being a palindrome and the math still will show that your conjecture is probably true.

So, primorial numbers are of the form $p_n\# \pm 1$, but that form is not easy to deal with as primes are complicated, so we will approximate it with:
$$p_n\# \pm 1 \sim e^n$$
So then let's think about the chance that a random number is a palindrome.  Well, the definition of a palindrome is that the first half of the digits are the same as the reverse of the last half of the digits.  Therefore if a number is about $10^x$ then the odds that it is a palindrome is $10^{x/2}$ because the first half of the digits can be anything, but the last half of the digits have to be match it.  The equation $10^x \to \frac{1}{10^{x/2}}$ is equivalent to $x \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ so well be using the $2$nd as it is easier to use.

Now let's consider asking how many primorial numbers are also a palindrome with the number $>10^{11}$, because there are no counterexamples to your conjecture at least up to over $10^{11}$. Well, starting with $n=11$ we get $p_n\# > 10^{11}$, so well write a sum starting with it:
$$(\text{Approximate number of palindrome primorials} > 10^{11}) \approx \sum_{k=11}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{e^x}}$$
*That last step might be a little confusing.  Basically, we are adding up the chances that the numbers are counterexamples to see how many (or little) we would expect.*

Next well write $\text{(Approximate number of palindrome primorials > 10000)}$ as $C$ for count.  Well also write $\sqrt{e^x}$ as $(\sqrt{e})^x$ to get:

$$C \approx \sum_{k=11}^\infty \frac{1}{(\sqrt{e})^x}$$

By solving the series we get: ([Wolfram page here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%201%2Fsqrt%28e%29%5Ex%2C%20x%3D11%20to%20infinity))

$$C \approx \frac{1}{(\sqrt{e} - 1)e^5}$$

Which means $C \approx 0.0103\dots$ which is less than a 1.1% chance!

To summarize what this is saying, is that the chance that besides the small examples you gave there is approximately less than a 1.1% chance that there is another.  This could be dramatically improved by just checking a few more primorials, and remember, this heuristic did not even take into account that the numbers have to be prime!

*If you have any questions, just ask!*

Comment: Also, my estimate does not include the fact that, except for 11, all palindromic primes have an odd number of digits.

Answer (score 3):

Let me try it.

**(1) You state:** "*the first few* primorial primes are..." from here we conclude that there exist more which not taken into account here (incomplete).

**(2) You state:** "*The first few* palindromic primes in base-10 are..." from here we conclude that there exist more which not taken into account here (incomplete).

**(3) You then state** (without any serious *heuristic justification*) based on a glance on the incomplete sequences listed in (1) and (2) that it *appears plausible* to state such being a conjecture; and that only what our eye obsevers up to some number in (1) and (2) would suffice to be *appearing plausible*.

Such statement, from a mathematician point of view shall not be termed as *conjecture* as long as no serious *heuristic justification* provided.

To your questions follows the answer based on the 3 steps above:

*What relationship(s) [if any] exist between primorial primes and palindromic primes?* No there is no explicit relationship, at least not any that is even heuristically justifiable.

*Is this conjecture known in the literature?* No there is not existing such statement. And honestly it would be rather absurd to believe that some matematician seriousely would make such statement termed as *conjecture* in the future except with a proper heuristic foundation.

*If so, does it have a name?* No indeed not.

Let me take another view on the standpoint for such a statement. Imagine, even if this would have been a *conjecture* based on a strong heuristic justification, and we could also provide a *proof* later on. So you would have then a *theorem* that would say $3,5,7$ are the only primes both palindromic and primorial. This would be as little spectacular as saying today that it would be a significant theorem to state that: the only integers which are both palindromic (or primorial) and Fermat number are $3,5$. Would that make sense? No!

Comment: Thank you for your (somewhat) detailed answer @al-Hwarizmi.  At any rate, my *heuristic justification* is that a *quick visual examination* of both lists give you (somewhat *immediately*) $3$, $5$ and $7$.  Notwithstanding, I suggest that you ask for the *motivation* for this question, rather than the heuristic justification. =)

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris, a quick visual examination is not at all the same as a heuristic justification. al-Hwarizmi is quite right to call you out on this. I would call your "conjecture" a wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

============ First Point ======================

I've noticed something rather unique to this specific palindrome pair :

- `16(7*)61`

  and
- `151`

It seems that, regardless of number of 7s, it's always divisible by `151`

Conversely, for palindromes in the form of `1(6+)1`

whenever it's a 2-factor only composite, and one of them
being `11`, then the other prime factor
must be a palindromic prime in the form `1(51)+`

I haven't tested all combinations of it,
but this `n` versus `n-1` relationship seems to be applicable

```
if n in [2:9]
```

Another similar type of repeating pattern,
while not being palindromic, is that numbers in the
form of `3(9*)6` are always(?) divisible by `36`,

in addition,

```
 whenever the the `# of 9s is odd`,
```

which is same as

```
 whenever `# of decimal digits is odd` for this set,
```

then it's also divisible by `11` ; underlying principle being

```
% echo '       11*36' | bc 
              396
% echo '      111*36' | bc
             3996
% echo '     1111*36' | bc 
            39996
% echo '    11111*36' | bc 
           399996
% echo '   111111*36' | bc 
          3999996
% echo '  1111111*36' | bc 
         39999996
% echo ' 11111111*36' | bc 
        399999996
```

================== Unrelated Second Point  ============

Perhaps other examples also exist, for now I've only
noticed that divisibility by palindromic primes of
`3` or `11` are what I call

```
horizontally-digit-agnostic (HDA)
```

meaning -

- horizontally reversing the decimal

  expansion of the digits of an integer,

  does **not**,
  alter its `divisibility by n`

e.g.

```
3614599901: 11 2423 135617
1099954163: 7 11 1733 8243
```

modulo `% 3` seems to be also HDA, but `% 11` isn't

here's a summary of other small primes evaluated against the HDA criteria

- 2     fails it by 4x         : 16 ->61, 61 is prime
- 5/7   fails it by 5x/7x      : 35 ->53, 53 is prime
  (also 20->02,30->03)
- 13/31 fails this on itself   : 13<->31, 13/31 both primes
- 17/71 fails this on itself   : 17<->71, 17/71 both primes
- 37/73 fails this on itself   : 37<->73, 37/73 both primes
- 19    fails it by 2x         : 38 ->83, 83 is prime
- 23    fails it by 4x         : 92 ->29, 29 is prime